# Is there a valid form of "aggregate" meaning "that can be aggregated"? Is "Aggregable" a word?

Tags: contemporary-english, word-formation

A thing that can be composted is compostable. I'm trying to describe a thing that can be aggregated. The probably self-invented word I'm using is "aggregable" and I'm struggling to find it floating about in the wild.

Is "aggregable" egregious or is "aggregable" acceptable? What would be a more easily understood but also compact phrasing of that concept?

The context of my question is in terms of data science: I'm naming a function in a program and naming things is hard. I'm looking for a reasonably compact way of saying "I'm preparing attributes of this element to be absorbed into a larger aggregation." I'm also trying to highlight the fact that only some of those aspects are "aggregable".

Example: "prep_aggregable_attribs()"

Comment: Have you checked a [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggregable)?

Comment: @KillingTime - I have! Have you? :) If you saw one that I didn't see, I'd love the link. EDIT: Oh. You gave it. Don't I feel silly.

Comment: Thank you for this question and fo providing some information about why you want this word.  Before anyone can respond, we need more information, please.  Can you explain what is being (or is capable of being "aggregated"?  In Latin, 'Grex' means 'flock'.  So to aggregate is to combine a number of things into a group, or, in a mathematical sense, add them up.  So do you mean by the word you are seeking that something is capable of being the member of a group of other things, or do you mean something which is, in effect, a group into which other things can be 'aggregated'?

Comment: Thanks for checking on me @Tuffy - I mean "capable of being grouped". e.g. a field containing Male and Female are aggregable.  A field containing ID numbers would be a useless thing to try to aggregate as each entry is unique, and operations like average or sum are nonsensical when applied to an ID number.  I did find the word, but thanks for the info about "Grex"!

Comment: In [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aggregable) too.

Comment: Groupable.  ToBeAggregated.  PreAggregate.  Clusterable.  Also note that when you're naming something in a program, you're not limited to words that are in the dictionary.

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks! Great suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I hate it when I think I've done research, and then it's apparent that I did it incompetently.

@KillingTime graciously provided [an appropriate link to a well respected dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggregable) in a comment.

**"Aggregable" is a word.**

Thank you sir!

EDIT: @livresque - Thanks for the sage advice. I've added the full definition bellow to allow this Question/Answer to be fully self contained.

---

## aggregable: adjective

*ag·​gre·​ga·​ble | \ ˈa-grə-gə-bəl \*

### Definition of aggregable

: that may be aggregated

//property aggregable with other property

*14-Dec-2021*, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggregable

Comment: I encourage you to include the dictionary entry information, not just the link, so that the answer with this dictionary reference will be self-contained.

Comment: 1) Welcome, and I hope you'll continue to contribute! 2) Self-answering is a great practice, but it's also great to refrain from answering questions that don't meet the [topic guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), including questions about words readily available in dictionaries.